# Matrix multiplication using CUDA:Wrong output

Tags: c, cuda, matrix-multiplication

I'm a beginner in `CUDA`. I am writing a program to multiply two matrices without using shared memory. Here's my program where I multiply 4x4 matrices filled with `1`.

The output is `26853932` where the correct output should be `4`.

Can someone please tell me where I am wrong. Maybe I've made a very naive mistake?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  

//kernel deifnition

__global__ void mulKernel(int *d_M,  int *d_N,  int *d_P,int width)
{
int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


if (row < width && col < width)
{
    int pvalue=0;
    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
    {
        pvalue = pvalue + (d_M[row*width + k] * d_N[k*width + col]);
    }

    d_P[row*width + col] = pvalue;
}
}

int main()
{
const int block_size = 2;
const int array_width = 4;
int h_M[array_width][array_width] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

int h_N[array_width][array_width] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int h_P[array_width][array_width];

int size = array_width*array_width*(sizeof(int));
int *d_M, *d_N, *d_P;

//memory allocation
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_M, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_N, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_P, size); 

//copy data from host to memory
cudaMemcpy(d_M, h_M, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_N, h_N, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 grid(array_width/block_size, array_width/block_size, 0);       //grid size
dim3 block(block_size, block_size, 0);  //block size

mulKernel << <grid, block >> >(d_M,d_N,d_P,array_width);

cudaMemcpy(h_P, d_P, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

printf("%d", h_P[0][0]);

printf("Press enter to exit....\n");
getchar();


}
```

Comment: The error is that you set the z-extent of your block and grid to `0`. A 2D grid is a 3D grid where one dimension is of length 1. If you leave out the last argument to `dim3` it is automatically set to `1`. Thus, just erase `,0` and your code works. For future posts: It is not necessary to include a completely irrelevant picture of the output. Instead write the wrong output **and** the expected output in text.

Comment: @havogt if you want to write an answer I would upvote.  The use of `0` as you indicate would actually throw a CUDA runtime error, which the posted code is not checking for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the lines

```
dim3 grid(array_width/block_size, array_width/block_size, 0);       //grid size
dim3 block(block_size, block_size, 0);  //block size
```

where the grid extent in z direction is set to 0. The correct representation of a 2D object in a 3D grid is to set the extent in one of the directions to 1.

The code works after replacing the `0` with `1` or by leaving out the 3rd argument (then it is default initialized to `1`):

```
dim3 grid(array_width/block_size, array_width/block_size );
dim3 block(block_size, block_size );
```

---

With the incorrect setup the runtime error `invalid configuration argument` is thrown on the kernel call. You could have easily found that yourself  by using [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/5085250) (or by running your program with `cuda-memcheck`).

Comment: Thanks man, how naive on my part to make such a silly mistake.Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of **GRID** & **BLOCK** configuration is wrong.

**Now:**

```
dim3 grid(array_width/block_size, array_width/block_size, 0);       //grid size
dim3 block(block_size, block_size, 0);  //block size
```

**Expected:**

```
dim3 grid(array_width/block_size, array_width/block_size, 1);       //grid size
dim3 block(block_size, block_size, 1);  //block size
```

Its good habit to use CUDA Error Statements. Following is the very easy example, just replace **stmt** with your expected code Statement.

```
#define wbCheck(stmt) do{
cudaError_t err = stmt;
if (err != cudaSuccess) {
printf( "Failed to run stmt %d ", __LINE__);
printf( "Got CUDA error ...  %s ", cudaGetErrorString(err));
return -1;
}
} while(0)
```